# PayPal IPN not firing on Reactivate Subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have set up a automatic billing subscription button,

When a user signs up, or we suspend a subscription, IPN sends data to our server, but when I click on the reactivate subscription link, to reactivate it, no IPN data is sent to our server.

I tried both setting the ipn url in paypal, and also setting the ipn url in the button and neither way seems to be firing on reactivation.

Is there something I am missing here that is making it not fire on reactivation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the [IPN variables documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id08CTB0S055Z), specifically the different values for txn_type, I don't see anything that would resemble a "reactivation" of a profile.  Unfortunately, it looks like that's simply not something that the system triggers.

If you need to activate the user account in your own system based on the profile getting reactivated what you could do is use the recurring_payment IPN instead.  This will be triggered as soon as the next payment for the profile happens, so in your system you could check the current status of the profile and update it need be when a payment actually occurs.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will do that, but that does seem like a fairly significant oversight :(

Comment: yet another reason I am not impressed by the PayPal IPN system

Comment: All of the new REST APIs work with Webhooks, which you'll like better than IPN I'm sure.  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/?mark=webhooks#overview